# gravity form updat calculation

Tags: forms, calculation, gravity

I am wondering if there is a way to cause all the Entries in a Form to be re-calculated (we use Gravity Forms eCommerce Fields and Gravity Forms Conditional Pricing) after a Product Price change?

We often keep and then update our Entries past the submission stage to make changes to it through the year. Doing it manually by individual Entry Edit (and re-submission) is one way, but with hundreds of records that can get tedious.

Another way we’ve found is using Inline Edit from Gravity View (speeds up the process a little but still a manual entry by entry process).

But other than Exporting all the data, manipulating it and the RE-Importing all the data to update existing records, I am wondering if it is theoretically (or practically) possible to cause a Form Entry Data Set to ALL be RE-submitted for calculations to be re-calculated at once?